# Non-defining relative clause omitting subject pronoun

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

the following sentence:

> Both actors involved, the company A and the
>   company B, decide on this basis if the water is boiled

In my understanding, this is a non-defining relative clause as it gives additional information that is not necessary determine which actors are concerned. Then, my textbook says it is necessary to put it in commas and to mention the subject pronoun. This would be something like

> Both actors involved, **which are** the company A and the
>   company B, decide on this basis if the water is boiled

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If your understanding is that ***which are*** is *grammatically necessary* then no - that's not correct (it's optional). But ***company A and company B*** (forget ***the*** - it's non-idiomatic in this context) is a parenthetical element which does normally need to be set off using commas (or brackets or dashes, for example).

Comment: I understand. May you elaborate what you mean by non-idiomatic in this context?

Comment: I mean *native speakers don't speak like that*. I wouldn't like to get bogged down in whether it's out-and-out *ungrammatical* to include those definite articles in your example, but it's ***so*** "unacceptable" you might as well assume it is.

Comment: You're probably right about it being non-restrictive ('the actors involved'  being defining,  'companies A and B' being vital but recoverable  information) but it's an appositive. Appositives are parentheticals.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a clause at all, not even a small clause, as it doesn't contain a verb or a participle. It's simply a noun phrase in apposition.

Comment: Looking at, say, *My friend John disagrees*, and *My friend, John, disagrees,* it seems to me the distinction between a "noun phrase in apposition" and a "parenthetical element" is fine to non-existent.